# How to list all of the commit ids with no Jira Issue defined in commit message

Tags: git, shell, unix, github

I have a development branch in GIt where developers have committed their changes and add Jira ticket in the messages. Also many of the commit doesn't have Jira ticket defined in the message

Now, I want to create a shell to get a list of all commit Ids including author, commit, commit, date where there is no Jira numbers have been added in the message section. This message is just have characters been defined

Answer (score 5):

there is the git log command:

```
git log --graph --abbrev-commit --decorate --format=format:'%h %ai %s - %an' --all
```

that you can pipe to
`grep -v <JiraPattern>` to suppress the commits having the JiraPattern.

Check [git format doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_commit_formatting) to perfectly fit your needs.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

```
git log -E --grep=<jirapattern> --invert-grep --pretty="%H %an %cn %cd %s" --all
```

`jirapattern` is a regex for the jira ticket. `--grep=<jirapattern> --invert-grep` limits the output to commits whose messages do not contain the jira ticket. You might also want to use `--no-merges` to exclude the merge commits, and `--data=format:"<formatstring>"` to format the committer date.

Comment: Thanks, It worked. Also what is the value for <jirapattern> I can add under --grep=<jirapattern>

Comment: @user2136881 Sorry, but I don't know what a jira ticket is exactly like. I can't write a a regex for it.

Comment: Jira ticket format is : PC-1825, PC-488, CCP-177, CLSNOW-956

Comment: @user2136881 Try `-E --grep="(CLSNOW|CCP|PC)-[0-9]+"`. If the number always has 3 or 4 digits, `[0-9]+` can be `[0-9]{3,4}`.